# How to create group by function for firstname,mark1,mark2,mark3?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have merged three tables using union query and created group by for id already.

### **Here is my code:**

```
select Id,                                                                       
Max(Firstname) Firstname,                                                       
Max(Mark1) Mark1,                                                              
Max(Mark2) Mark2,                                                               
Max(Mark3) Mark3                                                              

from
(
    select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent      
    union                                                                           
    select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child               
    union                                                                           
    select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark           
    ) t
    group by Id
```

What my question is will i able to create group by function for rest of the columns without using join query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to elaborate. Also, you are missing an open parentheses in your query.

Comment: I have created group by function for Id in the code itself already so my question is how to create group by function for rest of the columns such as firstname,mark1,mark2,mark3?

Comment: uh... add them to the select and group by clause. You didn't create a function...

Comment: select Id,                                                                                                                                  
MAX(Firstname)Firstname,
MAX(Mark1) Mark1,
MAX(Mark2) Mark2,
MAX(Mark3) Mark3
from
(
select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark
) t
group by Id,Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Mark3

So I'm getting this result.
http://imgur.com/a/Ebl8C